# plane detection with react-three/xr

Tags: reactjs, three.js, next.js, react-three-fiber, webxr

I`m using react-three/xr and react-three/drei in my next.js project. This code put the 3d model i an static position.

```
const Test: NextPage = () => {
return (
    <div className="testar">
        <ARCanvas>
            <ambientLight />
            <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
            <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                <Model scale={0.01} />
            </Suspense>
        </ARCanvas>
    </div>
);
```

};

and it works correctly. now how can I detect the flat surface to place the object?

Answer (score 1):

Add `sessionInit={{ requiredFeatures: ['hit-test'] }` to your AR canvas then use hit test to get the it location and add it as reference to your model

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-three/xr

```js
export default function App(){
 
 let hitPoint = useRef()

     useHitTest((hitMatrix, hit) => {
        hitMatrix.decompose(
            hitPoint.current.position, 
            hitPoint.current.rotation, 
            hitPoint.current.scale,
        )
     })

 return(     
      <ARCanvas sessionInit={{ requiredFeatures: ['hit-test'] }}>
        <Model ref={hitPoint} />
     </ARCanvas>
 );
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. I don't understand how to use this code to detect a plane (a floor for example). Could you include a little more of the surrounding code to provide context?

Comment: @BillO should be good now.

Comment: Any ideas what this needs to be with the new `<XR>` component in version 5.x.x of `react-xr` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the clues here to construct a simple model in [codesandbox](https://ioyf08.csb.app/). (Code shown below)

The experience on my phone is that the model shows up nicely. When I click the `Start AR` button the box appears about where I am standing, about a meter off the ground.

However, I can't drag to place the box, and I don't see a reticle.

**Do I need to process the hit result explicitly?**

This isn't an answer, but this code might be informative for someone.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { ARCanvas, useHitTest } from "@react-three/xr";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";

export default function App() {
  // wrap to avoid error: React-three-fiber hooks can only be used within the Canvas
  function Model() {
    let hitPoint = useRef();

    useHitTest((hitMatrix, hit) => {
      hitMatrix.decompose(
        hitPoint.current.position,
        hitPoint.current.rotation,
        hitPoint.current.scale
      );
    });

    return <boxGeometry ref={hitPoint} args={[1, 1, 1]} />;
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "lightblue", height: "100vh" }}>
      <ARCanvas sessionInit={{ requiredFeatures: ["hit-test"] }}>
        <mesh>
          <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
          <directionalLight position={[-10, -10, -10]} />
          <Model />
          <meshStandardMaterial color="orange" />
        </mesh>
        <OrbitControls />
      </ARCanvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm finding that the hittest isn't being triggered, I thought it might happen when I tapped the screen, but nothing is logging in the hitMatrix or hit..